# Python3 if if else

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, python-3.6

When i do this in this way

```
x = "Hello"
if len(x) <= 9:
    print("The password must contain at least 9 letters")
if x[0].islower():
    print("The first password letter must be uppercase")
else:
    print("Password saved")
    password = x
```

i getting

```
>The password must contain at least 9 letters
>Password saved
```

What should I do to make the program stop on:

```
>The password must contain at least 9 letters
```

Comment: Use if-elif-else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `elif` between `if` and `else`:

```
x = "Hello"
if len(x) <= 9:
    print("The password must contain at least 9 letters")
elif x[0].islower():
    print("The first password letter must be uppercase")
else:
    print("Password saved")
    password = x
```

`elif` is executed only when `if` wasn't executed, and `elif`'s condition is true. You can also chain as many `elif`s as you want, in which case the first `elif` whose condition matches is executed.

---

**Update:** Since OP said in comments that he wants all errors to be shown at once, I would use something like this:

```
x = "Hello"
errors = []
if len(x) <= 9:
    errors.append("The password must contain at least 9 letters")
if x[0].islower():
    errors.append("The first password letter must be uppercase")

if errors:
    print('\n'.join(errors))
else:
    print("Password saved")
    password = x
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have two if filters in the code. I'm assuming you want the structure where both `"The password must contain at least 9 letters"` and `"The first password letter must be uppercase"`can be returned if both their conditions are met.

If, however, you don't need this capability, simply replace the second `if` with an `elif` and it should work.

If you need this capability, try something like:

```
x = "Hello"
if len(x) <= 9:
    print("The password must contain at least 9 letters")
if x[0].islower():
    print("The first password letter must be uppercase")
if len(x) >= 9 and x[0].isupper():
    print("Password saved")
    password = x
```

This simply adds a third if statement testing that the previous conditions were fulfilled.

Comment: It is hardly a good idea to make the final `if` statement re-calculate the conditions (in reverse) that were already verified. This doubles the computational complexity! See my answer for a way to re-use the calculated values.